# Main content is overlapping on footer section PDF document iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

i am using itextsharp for creating document. I have created a footer section in document but content that over the top of footer is overlapping.

How can i fix this?

I want to add page number on each page how can i do this?

Please check this link
[Pdf document Image](http://i1008.photobucket.com/albums/af204/shoaibshah01/Untitled_zps07f7cdd0.jpg)

```
 public class PdfNote
 {
    public int Create(int id, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var file = path;

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                System.IO.File.Delete(file);

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

            var writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new System.IO.FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));
            document.Open();

            writer.PageEvent = new Footer();

            // main content

            document.Close();

            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public partial class Footer : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
        {
            PdfPTable fTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            fTbl.TotalWidth = 550;
            fTbl.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

            PdfPTable line = new PdfPTable(1);
            line.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
            line.DefaultCell.BorderWidthBottom = 0.2f;
            line.DefaultCell.Padding = 5;
            line.AddCell("");

            fTbl.AddCell(line);

            PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(3);
            footerTbl.TotalWidth = 550;
            footerTbl.DefaultCell.Column.Alignment = 1;
            footerTbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            footerTbl.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

            footerTbl.AddCell("Print Name:");
            footerTbl.AddCell("Signature:");
            footerTbl.AddCell("Date:");


            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.Padding = 20;
            cell.Border = 0;
            cell.BorderWidthBottom = 1;

            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);
            footerTbl.AddCell(cell);

            fTbl.AddCell(footerTbl);
            fTbl.AddCell(line);

            fTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 110, writer.DirectContent);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### In a nutshell:

In

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
```

you tell iText to hardly leave any margin (e.g. for use for footer lines) at all. Thus, it is not surprising that your footer

```
fTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 110, writer.DirectContent);
```

every so often overlaps the content.

So simply adjust the margins (especially the bottom one) and the footer position to not overlap each other.

### In more detail:

The `Document` constructor you use is documented as

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs a new Document-object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pageSize">the pageSize</param>
/// <param name="marginLeft">the margin on the left</param>
/// <param name="marginRight">the margin on the right</param>
/// <param name="marginTop">the margin on the top</param>
/// <param name="marginBottom">the margin on the bottom</param>
public Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom) {
```

Thus your `new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10)` instructs iText to create a document in A4 size and to merely leave 10 points free margin space in every direction when filling it with content. 10 points ain't much.

The table writing method of `PdfPTable` you use is documented as

```
/**
 * Writes the selected rows to the document.
 *
 * @param rowStart the first row to be written, zero index
 * @param rowEnd   the last row to be written + 1. If it is -1 all the
 *                 rows to the end are written
 * @param xPos     the x write coordinate
 * @param yPos     the y write coordinate
 * @param canvas   the <CODE>PdfContentByte</CODE> where the rows will
 *                 be written to
 * @return the y coordinate position of the bottom of the last row
 */
public float WriteSelectedRows(int rowStart, int rowEnd, float xPos, float yPos, PdfContentByte canvas)
```

Thus, your code

```
fTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 15, 110, writer.DirectContent);
```

starts drawing the table at the coordinate (15, 110) --- the origin (0, 0) here is the bottom left corner of your document.

Thus, obviously, page content area and footer area overlap in the stripe 10 <= y <= 110. You should increase the bottom margin (the last parameter in your `Document` constructor) and decrease the y position of the table drawing call to not overlap anymore.

Comment: Sorry, i am using firt time this library so i cannot understand your reply. please explain. thank you

Comment: I added some details.